# Duplicate database and insert values

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I duplicate some records from one table and insert to second table.

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO pending_payments (user_id, course_id, amount)
    SELECT user_id,course_id,monthly_subscription_fee
    FROM enrol
    WHERE active_shop='1'";
```

Okay, but Now I duplicate this records:
user_id,course_id,monthly_subscription_fee

and I need add  some custom values.

I show on second query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pending_payments (data_added, type_fee)
    VALUES ('_current_data', 'subscription');
```

Can anyone help me merge this both sql query into one? to run at the same time?

[image]

Comment: When you want to insert data into an existing record, you should use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Comment: this is sql which runs cron and creates pending payments. So I don't want to use update - just create this record with all the values at once according to screenshot. So i need update only current created records (not all records in table). Can you  help me?

Comment: Just change your SELECT statement to include these extra columns and their values

Comment: It is totally unclear why you did not try/do: `INSERT INTO pending_payments (user_id, course_id, amount, data_added, type_fee) SELECT user_id, course_id, monthly_subscription_fee, '_current_data', 'subscription') WHERE active_shop='1'";`